# How to input a character and then output a number sequence dependent on value of char?

Tags: c++

so I'm trying to write a program that would take an input character between 0 and 127 and then output a string of numbers in the following form:

```
 - If I input a 0, the output should be a 0
 - If I input a 5, the output should be 012345
 - If I input a 9, the output should be 0123456789
 - If I input a 14, the output should be 012345678901234
 - If I input a 27, the output should be 0123456789012345678901234567
```

So, I'm looking for increments of 10 characters from 0 to 9 at most and then repeat the sequence until the last number is reached.  So in 27, there's actually 28 characters output due to the first 0, but the last one is still a 7.

I know I want to use for loops, but I'm having a bit of a trouble figuring out how to make this happen.  I can probably use the the ASCII 48 through 57 for the output, but my problem is how I make the input work... should I static cast it to an integer and then work with that?  I'm kind of hitting a wall here.

Comment: convert to `int N`, loop `i=0` thru `N`, printing `i % 10` every iteration. Regarding the input, `strtol()`, `atoi()` etc, are all candidates, though I would likely just `int N; if (cin >> N) {.. loop ..}`. The output can be strictly digits.

Comment: My concern with the conversion to int is that it uses a number from ASCII character index depending on the first number of the input.  So if I convert 127 to int, it'll actually be 49 (which is 1 in the table).  And if I input 0, and then convert it to int, it'll convert it as 48.... so it'll run the loop that many times.  I have to have char as an input, not an int.

Comment: table?? what table?? The first utterance of it is in the comment you just left; there is no mention of a "table" in the question at all. And if you convert `"127"` to `int` it better be `127`. No casts. *Use a conversion routine*, be it the one built into the stream extraction operator or something like `strtol()`.

Comment: Well, I did mention in my question that input has to be a character between 0 and 127.  Should I use something like stringstream for conversion?

Comment: What do you want the program to do on invalid input? You could go `if(input < 0 || input >127) { // print bad input } else { //do loop`

Comment: @Noobacode Suppose I open a file that has your input data in it. *What does it look like?* Is it a *single* 8-bit signed binary value between 0 and 0x7F? or is it the *characters* ranging from '0'.. to possibly '1', '2', '7'? The latter requires conversion to an `int` type, the former can just be used straight away in the algorithm David provided below without any conversion.

Comment: Well, invalid input is not hard to figure out, but my problem is the input of the character and putting out that string of numbers in that format.  If input was just an integer, it wouldn't be a problem at all.  WhozCraig:  Input has to be in char form.  So, cin>>char.   I want to have a main() function that does all the prompting and input, and then char is sent to an outputFunction(char input) that accepts char as an argument.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid that doesn't answer the question. However, the question you asked in your post which you pointed out "would take **an** input character between 0 and 127..." and your first comment here, "...depending on the **first** number of the input.." are contradictory. So again. *Is your input data a single 8 bit signed binary value, or is it a sequence of one-or-more digits represented as ASCII characters?* The answer to that question will ultimately determine whether you need to perform a conversion or just start using your data straight away. It *sounds* like the latter.

Comment: @WhozCraig  that seconds comment is not a requirement, it's just something I noticed from experimenting.  If I try to convert it only takes first digit into account for conversion.   The input is in a single form.  So, I want a user to type a number from 0 to 127, and then I want to produce that sequence of numbers depending on his input.  The primary requirement is that input from the user HAS to be of char type.

Comment: Ok. That makes more sense. Davids code does that. It takes input in character form *and* converts it to a signed-`int` value for you. You can type "0" enter, or "127" enter, or "200000" enter, if you want to limit the value typed to be between 0 and 127 *at data entry time before enter is pressed*, there is no portable way to do it. But you *can* validate it after enter is pressed, and request it again (or exit) if the value is not in the range 0.. 127. Does that make sense? [See it live](http://ideone.com/9U9EnE) for an example.

Comment: It does; however, here's a problem.  I need to separate this program into two functions.  main() and something like output().  output() has to take one argument of char type, so output(char).  It then has to produce the number sequence.

Comment: Hmmmmmm here's the code I came up with (with your and David's help), and it works... but why does it work? http://codepad.org/BTCicfcC  Why is it letting me put an int type into an argument that requires char? I understand that char is the smallest integer type...... could that be the reason?

Comment: To avoid making this a chat, I'll figure out that one a bit later on, since it's doing what I want it to now.  I'll probably join a chat room and find out more on that.  But I appreciate you helping me.  You gave me your time and I'm thankful.  I gave David credit for correct answer, but you guys both helped me a ton.

Comment: @Noobacode David deserves the answer credit. it was, after all, his code. Regarding how/why that worked. It is called an integer promotion (though in this case it is more like a demotion). I won't bore you with the details of the standard, but if you're interested, do some searching on it (C++ integer promotions). And glad you solved your assignment.

Comment: @WhozCraig ahhh, that makes perfect sense, since it's part of the integer family (long, int, short, char).  Awesome, thank you once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   char input;

   std::cin >> input;

   if (input >= 0 && input <= 127) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) std::cout << i % 10;
   }
}
```

Comment: (a) `i <= n` should be sufficient for the conditional, and (b) why the ternary condition? just `std::cout << (i % 10)` should be sufficient.

Comment: The ternary operator seems a bit unneeded `if (i<=9) i == i%10` any way.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, was just trying to be careful.

Comment: Here's the problem guys, input has to be a character between 0 and 127.  So it has to be in the form of char input; cin>>input; and then from that I have to do the number sequence.

Comment: @Noobacode That's no problem, all you have to do is make a simple range check with an if statement.

Comment: @David Yes, it has to be cin>>char;